# .NET XML serializer and XHTML string in object property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xhtml, xml-serialization

I have a class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://test/v1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://test/v1", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Data
{
    ...
    public object Comment { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The **Comment property** is of type `object` because it is declared as type `any` in the xml schema. It's declared as any to allow both text and xhtml data. I can't change the schema - it's related to an international standard.

Single-line content (string):

```
<Comment>This is a single line text</Comment>
```

Multi-line content (xhtml):

```
<Comment>
   <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">This is text<br />with line breaks<br />multiple times<div>
</Comment>
```

The `XmlSerializer` won't allow me to plug an `XmlElement` into the `object Comment` property of the auto-generated Data class. I've also tried to create a custom `IXmlSerializer` implementation for XHtml, but then the XSD-generated Comment property needs to be declared as that exact type (instead of object).

The custom XHtml type I'm trying to set on the Comment property looks like this;

```
[XmlRoot]
public class XHtmlText : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { } // Only used for serializing to XML

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (Content.IsEmpty()) return;

        writer.WriteStartElement("div", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
        var lines = Content.Split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = lines[i];
            writer.WriteRaw(line);
            if (i < lines.Length - 1) writer.WriteRaw("<br />");
        }
        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}
```

Exception from the XmlSerializer:

> InvalidOperationException: The type Lib.Xml.XHtmlText may not be used
>   in this context. To use Lib.Xml.XHtmlText as a parameter, return type,
>   or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return type, or member
>   must be declared as type Lib.Xml.XHtmlText (it cannot be object).
>   Objects of type Lib.Xml.XHtmlText may not be used in un-typed
>   collections, such as ArrayLists

The serialization code:

```
    var data = new Lib.Xml.Data { Content = "test\ntest\ntest\n" };

    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
        Indent = false,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = omitDeclaration,
    };

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType(), new[] { typeof(Lib.Xml.XHtmlText) });
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the solution.

I can't set the comment to an instance of XmlElement

```
data.Comment = commentAsXhtmlXmlElement;
```

but I can (somehow) assign an array of XmlNode

```
data.Comment = new XmlNode[] { commentAsXhtmlXmlElement };
```

Found out when I deserialized an inbound xml-instance of the data POCO.

Strange.